# The expression "elements of context"

Tags: expressions

Having trouble for what should be a simple thing:

I want to refer to recently found information regarding the context of specific songs: when they were created, who first sang them, where, etc

Is the expression "new (or additional) *elements of context*" correct?

It does not seem to be used that much.

Would "contextual material" be better?  Any other suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with *elements of context* but it sounds to me more suited to an academic paper. I would suggest *background information* might be a natural way to say it. One of the components might then be a *bit of background* although that is more informal.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the "academic paper" version is indeed the one I was looking for. A last question, if I may: would "New elements of context regarding song X" be correct? and convey what I mentioned in my question which is that new information regarding the context of this song has been unearthed? Would "New elements regarding the context of song X" be correct? Better? Thanks a lot

Comment: Either would be fine in the context of an academic paper. In everyday language I would probably prefer _about_ to _regarding_ but that is a personal preference.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your answers